# PHP Header redirect with Radio button

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, header

I've got this code from the web. It functions with my setup, calling the command all ok, i have the variables entered correctly.

But the if .. else statement redirects to only one URL, not the if statement, but only the else. so no matter what radio i select the https://thisdomain.com/1-2/ domain loads.

Here is the PHP/Html code:

```
<?php
$radio832112001 = intval($_POST['radio832112001']);

if ($radio832112001 === 2)
{
    header("Location: https://thisdomain.com/2-2/");
    die;
}
else
{
    header("Location: https://thisdomain.com/1-2/");
    die;
}
?>



    <form action="https://thisdomain.com/code/action-900.php">
      <input type="radio" id="no" name="radio832112001" value="2">
      <label for="indoor-220">No</label>
      <input type="radio" id="yes" name="radio832112001" value="1">
      <label for="outdoor-220">Yes</label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

What am i missing?

Cheers in advance.

Steve

Comment: Try action empty and add method :  `action="" method="POST"`

Answer (score 1):

You are using **GET** method in your form by not declaring `method` keyword. Replace

```
$radio832112001 = intval($_POST['radio832112001']);
```

by

```
$radio832112001 = intval($_GET['radio832112001']);
```

or add `method="POST"` to your **form** tag.

Answer (score 1):

```html
$radio832112001 = intval($_POST['radio832112001']); with:
$radio832112001 = intval($_GET['radio832112001']); or
add method="POST" to your form tag.
```

This worked. With updating the for="" code too. It was wrong. Now it all works as intended.

Thanks all